# How to get rows from one dataframe if values are in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe that is a result set of dropping duplicates from another dataframe.

```
changes = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type', 'Sum of Premium'], keep='last')
```

Then I have another where the ID and Plan Type is still listed twice

```
dupe_accts = changes.set_index(['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type']).index.get_duplicates()
```

What I'm trying to do now is have a third dataframe that would be if ID and plan type are in

```
dupe_accts
```

it would output the rows from

```
changes
```

into a new dataframe

So far I have

```
dupes = changes[['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type']].isin(dupe_accts)
```

but this is outputting

```
False False
False False
False False
False False
False False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set the index and get dupes that way.  You can use [**`duplicated`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to get a boolean array and mask the `change` dataframe with that.

The `keep=False` parameter will identify all duplicates.  This is opposed to the other options in which it will not identify the first or last as a duplicate.

```
duplicated = changes.duplicated(
    subset=['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type'], keep=False)
dupe_accts = changes[duplicated]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you